# Selenium with cron

Tags: python, selenium, pip

I wrote a small script with python3 and i use there selenium. everything working if I run python command from console but if I want to run it with cronetab script in log has an this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tom/Desktop/project/bot.py", line 5, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

selenium is installed with pip3 and in cron tab i have this lines for run my script:

```
19 * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/tom/Desktop/project/bot.py > /tmp/birdz_bot.txt 2>&1
```

i used only html unit driver, no gui
what can I do? THX!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had similar `crontab` problems like this before that ended up being caused by missing environment variables. `crontab` doesn't have access to the same environment variables as your console. The answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables) recommends something like:

```
19 * * * * . $HOME/.profile; /usr/bin/python3 /home/tom/Desktop/project/bot.py > /tmp/birdz_bot.txt 2>&1
```